# regex help... php check entry format

Tags: php, mysql, regex, forms

Im using php to develop an application, but I am running into some issues with regex...

I found a few sites that explain it, but it is for some reason over my head? can someone please help explain regex arguements?

I uploaded a sample of what I am working on [here](http://3rdrockmarketing.com/CLIENTsites/regex/)...

First, click on the "+" button at top right to get to the add content view.

Basically, I need it so when you submit from this form, php will check that the values are formatted correctly.

**Domain:** this can be .com, .co, .biz, .info, etc... User can enter the prefix, like a url, and php gets rid of it... so the ending strings in the array are just domain.com

```
domain1.com 
somedomain.biz
mydomain.co
```

**Redirect:** with this one, php uses the ',' so we are left with the ip, and the domainkey as seperate strings, the ip can be 2-3 numbers per section!, so ###.##.##.###, or even ##.##.##.##, and the domain key is a varchar(not so important)

```
##.##.##.##, domainkey
###.###.###.###, domainkey
```

**Solution for redirect:**

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

**/24's:** this is similar to the redirect IP, but the end will always end in '0/24'

```
##.##.###.0/24
##.##.###.0/24
```

**Names:*** This one should be the easiest, it can only be letters, no numbers... any length... *

```
randomname
thisisaname
```

Comment: We don't care what languages you use on your site, tag the question with what is relevant, in this case jQuery, HTML5 and CSS3 seems completely irrelevant to the question you are asking!

Comment: Rephrasing @adeneo, in what language you need the solution?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a "write my programs for me" site.

Comment: I understand this, that is why I asked... "can someone please help explain regex arguements?"  I thought this site was professional advise???  I tried, (\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}, which works for the redirect IP, but the /24 is formatted xx.xx.xx.0/24. not, xx.xx.xx.xx........

Comment: Trim down your question to only include what is relevant. If you're asking for just regex help, why do you tell us you're using HTML5, CSS3, PHP, MySQL and jQuery? And how is the PHP function you've pasted relevant? How are forms even relevant to this?

Comment: If you already have a solution for your redirect IP problem, why are you asking for help with it?

Comment: because while you guys are telling me how to ask my question, I have been continuing my research on the subject... I am actively working on it.

Comment: And you've left this question open because....?

Comment: Still looking for the solution... for the other 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest using some software or even website that allows you to test your regex. Such as:

- [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)
- [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)
- [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
- [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)
- [RegexDesigner](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)
- [etc](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/regular-expression-tools-resources/)

It really depends on how strict you want to get with it and how fancy you want to make your regex.

`/((\d{1,3}).){3}(\d{1,3})(\/\d{2})?/`